# TwitterWidget within SilverStripe

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, document.write, silverstripe

I am trying to integrate TwitterWidget within SilverStripe.

That's the plugin I am trying to use:
https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

If I put this code in a simple *.html file the widget works. Unfortunately I get an error if I try to use it in a *.ss file.

I downloaded the source code to find out where the error occurs. After several hours I found something pretty confusing:

That's the piece of code where the error occurs:

`document.write('<div class="twtr-widget" id="'+this.id+'"></div>')`

FireBug:

`uncaught exception: [Exception... "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" code: "11" nsresult: "0x8053000b (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_STATE_ERR)" location: "http://www.domain.com/mysite/javascript/widget.js?m=1321187964 Line: 257"]
LeftAn...8532904 (Zeile 883)
function() {return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')},`

After a few refreshes sometimes FireBug reports:

`An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
[Bei diesem Fehler anhalten] document.write('<div class="twtr-widget" id="'+this.id+'"></div>')`

Google Chrome JavaScript Debugger:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Document> has no method 'write'  //widget.js:257
TWTR.Widget.init                                              //widget.js:257
TWTR.Widget                                                   //widget.js:211
(anonymous function)                                          //?stage=Stage&flush=1:117
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWith                              //jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
e.extend.ready                                                //jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C                                          //jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little incomplete to debug, but why not use one of the readily available widgets? Like http://www.silverstripe.org/twitter-widget-pack-widget/

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :) I think I will use it for now. But still I would like to know why this plugin doesn't work. Can you tell which pieces of information are missing to debug it ?

Comment: Which version of SilverStripe, any other modules / customization,...?
Ideally you could provide a link to the (not working) page.
I'd suspect some JS clash. You could try to experiment in your Page_Controller with `Requirements::block(THIRDPARTY_DIR . '/jquery/jquery.js');` etc. - but this is only a wild guess.

Comment: First of all thanks for the help. I tried multiplle variation of importing Javascript with SilverStripe. I am using SS 2.4.5.

However, I accepted the answer a bit too early. Unfortunetly the widget doesn't work either. But I found out what causes the problem. It was a single line.Actually the first which specified XML Encoding: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` Can anyone tell me which I have to use, since I don't want to just delete it.

Comment: Ok, some background on the XML declaration (German, but judging from your first message that should be fine): http://de.selfhtml.org/html/xhtml/unterschiede.htm#xml_deklaration


But I'd strongly advocate switching to HTML5. SilverStripe supports it (or is agnostic to it), it's the future, and you don't need to fight with the XML declaration.
Does it work with HTML5 (http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp for example)?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Right under the XML declaration there was a HTML4.0.1 declaration. It works fine with it. Does that mean I actually can leave the XML declaration out?

Comment: If you're using HTML4 (or HTML5): yes - leave it out, you aren't using XML anyway.
Only in XHTML files the first line **should** be the XML declaration.